# Generate a stand-alone binary package for Qt in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, qt, compilation, ubuntu-18.04

I install Qt by building the Qt sources in order to specify some configuration parameters (e.g., enable MySQL database driver).

How can I generate a stand-alone binary package including Qt libraries and Qt Creator with my configuration for Linux such as [Qt offline installer](https://www.qt.io/offline-installers)? This makes us no longer need to compile Qt sources again in another system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Build Qt as static libs, like all the other library dependencies, and then generate a single big statically linked executable.
2. Keep binary linking, and package your application with the Qt libraries and other dependencies using the [qt installer framework](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/index.html) or an alternative like [InstallBuilder](https://installbuilder.bitrock.com/).
3. Swallow the red pill, and create [distro independent packages](https://www.datamation.com/open-source/linux-solutions-snappy-flatpak-and-appimage.html): Snappy, FlatPack or [AppImage](https://docs.appimage.org). The latter is what I prefer for my [VMPK](http://vmpk.sourceforge.net/#Download)